# UISearchBar animating into place when superview lays out subviews. How to disable?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, uiviewanimation

**My issue:**
I have a user onboarding process that makes use of a `UINavigationController` to present each step in the onboarding process. When pushing view controllers with `UISearchBar`s within them, the `UISearchBar`s are animating into place.

**What my issue looks like:** https://youtu.be/TKPLeJ9FmI4 (issue occurs around [0:27](https://youtu.be/TKPLeJ9FmI4?t=27), [0:32](https://youtu.be/TKPLeJ9FmI4?t=32), [0:41](https://youtu.be/TKPLeJ9FmI4?t=41))

**What I've gathered:** This seems to happen when the previous view controller in the stack performs an asynchronous function just before it pushes the next view controller, and, presumably, doesn't complete the asynchronous function until after the `UISearchBar` has already animated into place.

**What I've tried:** I tried subclassing `UISearchBar` and ensuring that `layoutSubviews` is not animated via `UIView.performWithoutAnimation`:

```swift
import UIKit

class SearchBar: UISearchBar {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            super.layoutSubviews()
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly, I tried ensuring that the `UISearchBar`'s superview is not animating when laying out subviews:

```swift
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        }
    }
}
```

**What I'm wondering:** As it is hard to pin down the exact cause of the animations, I am curious if there is a way to simply prevent the `UISearchBar` from animating altogether. There will never really be a time in which I need animate the `UISearchBar`.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me in Objective-C. It looks like you're compentent enough to translate this to Swift:

```
  [[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                                forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny
                                    barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

  [[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                                forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny
                                    barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefaultPrompt];

[self.searchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:finalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Where "finalImage" is an image you draw in code that returns a UIImage of the same rect size as the UISearchBar. You can find methods to draw an image of the background color you wish and then round the image corners. Here it is in Objective-C as well.

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color withSize:(CGRect)imageRect {
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageRect.size);
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
  CGContextFillRect(context, imageRect);

  UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return image;
}

- (UIImage *)roundImage:(UIImage *)image withRadius:(CGFloat)radius {
  CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  rect.size = image.size;
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
  UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect
                                                  cornerRadius:radius];
  [path addClip];
  [image drawInRect:rect];

  image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return image;
}
```

so the full declaration of the UISearchBar would be this:

```
  self.searchBar = [UISearchBar new];
  CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 44, 35);
  UIImage *colorImage = [self imageWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] withSize:rect];
  UIImage *finalImage = [self roundImage:colorImage withRadius:10.0];
  [self.searchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:finalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [self.searchBar setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:false];
  [self.view addSubview:self.searchBar];
```

This is the only way I've found to remove all funky animation added by Apple and to customize the background as you wish. Good luck (and for those who will downvote this because it's not in Swift, you should know that Swift is Ruby 2.0 and a meme language until real coders make it not a meme language, so stick with Objective-C).

Good Luck

EDIT

make sure you're setting constraints if you use layout constraints, if you don't use constraints, then remove

```
  [self.searchBar setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:false];
```

and then set the frame of the UISearchBar

Comment: It seems so hacky, but I’ll definitely try it tomorrow. Thanks for the suggestion. I wish I could just figure out how to disable the thing. If I get it to work I’ll post the Swift translation and you can edit your answer if you’d like

Comment: One issue I am having with your method, is that setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` for `searchBar` is causing `searchBar` to not appear on screen. Omitting this line keeps `searchBar` on the screen, but the animation still appears.

Comment: oh yeah, @DavidChopin, don't set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false if your'e setting the frame. i use this method with constraints inside a subclassed uiview which i use to as the viewcontroller;s view and call loadView, so i do this all programmatically, it may work differently if you set frame rather than use constraints.

Comment: Yeah so I realized I should probably add the `UISearchBar` programmatically, which I did, while implementing your method. Ended up setting its frame to `CGRect(x: 0, y: view.safeAreaInsets.top, width: view.frame.width, height: 56)`. Still wasn't working for me oddly enough. :/

Comment: Even when setting the frame instead of using interface builder/constraints, I needed to set `translatesAutoresizingMasIntoConstraints` to `false` for the `UISearchBar` to even appear.

Comment: @DavidChopin let me check this out later tonight/tomorrow, ill recreate what you're doing and see if i can solve it. i've spent days and days over the years working out kinks with UIsearchbar and i know the feelz on this on this, give me like 24 hours. this wouldl solve the problem for every coder who hates UISearchBar, this works for me perfectly but let me flex my Swift muslces and see what changes happen

Comment: I reverted to interface builder/constraints, but could go back to programmatically adding the bar/setting the frame if need be.

Comment: But yeah this could be a lucrative answer, assuming many others are having weird `UISearchBar` behavior. Let me know if you need any info/code